# How to properly use shared_ptr in good C++ APIs

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm currently trying to find out how to properly use the `shared_ptr` feature of C++11 in C++ APIs. The main area where I need it is in container classes (Like nodes in a scene graph for example which may contain a list of child nodes and a reference to the parent node and stuff like that). Creating copies of the nodes is not an option and using references or pointers is pain in the ass because no one really knows who is responsible for destructing the nodes (And when someone destructs a node which is still referenced by some other node the program will crash).

So I think using `shared_ptr` may be a good idea here. Let's take a look at the following simplified example (Which demonstrates a child node which must be connected to a parent node):

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Parent {};

class Child {
    private:
        shared_ptr<Parent> parent;
    public:
        Child(const shared_ptr<Parent>& parent) : parent(parent) {}
        Parent& getParent() { return *parent.get(); }
};

int main() {
    // Create parent
    shared_ptr<Parent> parent(new Parent());

    // Create child for the parent
    Child child(parent);

    // Some other code may need to get the parent from the child again like this:
    Parent& p = child.getParent();

    ...        

    return 0;
}
```

This API forces the user to use a `shared_ptr` for creating the actual connection between the child and the parent. But in other methods I want a more simple API, that's why the `getParent()` method returns a reference to the parent and not the `shared_ptr`.

My first question is: Is this a correct usage of `shared_ptr`? Or is there room for improvement?

My second question is: How do I properly react on null-pointers? Because the `getParent` method returns a reference the user may think it never can return NULL. But that's wrong because it will return NULL when someone passes a shared pointer containing a null-pointer to the constructor. Actually I don't want null pointers. The parent must always be set. How do I properly handle this? By manually checking the shared pointer in the constructor and throwing an exception when it contains NULL? Or is there a better way? Maybe some sort of non-nullable-shared-pointer?

Comment: These are many questions in one question. I'd move the NULL-questions to a separate question.

Comment: IMHO this is a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "no one really knows who is responsible for destructing the nodes" - perhaps you should do something about that disaster, rather than papering over the cracks with a dodgy shared-ownership model.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using shared pointers for the purpose you describe is reasonable and increasingly common in C++11 libraries.

A few points to note:

- On an API, taking a `shared_ptr` as an argument forces the caller construct a `shared_ptr`.  This is definitely a good move where there is a transfer of ownership of the pointee. In cases where the function merely uses a `shared_ptr`, it may be acceptable to take a reference to the object or the `shared_ptr`
- You are using `shared_ptr<Parent>` to hold a back reference to the parent object whilst using one in the other direction.    This will create a retain-cycle resulting in objects that never get deleted.  In general, used a `shared_ptr` when referencing from the top down, and a `weak_ptr` when referencing up.   Watch out in particular for delegate/callback/observer objects - these almost always want a `weak_ptr` to the callee.  You also need to take care around lambdas if they are executing asynchronously.  A common pattern is to capture a `weak_ptr`.
- Passing shared pointers by reference rather than value is a stylistic point with arguments for and against.  Clearly when passing by reference you are not passing ownership (e.g. increasing the reference count on the object). On the other hand, you are also not taking the overhead either.  There is a danger that you under reference objects this way.  On a more practical level, with a C++11 compiler and standard library, passing by value should result in a move rather than copy construction and be very nearly free anyway.  However, passing by reference makes debugging considerably easier as you won't be repeatedly stepping into `shared_ptr`'s constructor.
- Construct your `shared_ptr` with `std::make_shared` rather than `new()` and `shared_ptr`'s constructor

  `shared_ptr<Parent> parent = std::make_shared<Parent>();`

  With modern compilers and libraries this can save a call to `new()`.
- both `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` can contain `NULL` - just as any other pointer can.  You should always get in the habit of checking before dereferencing and probably `assert()`ing liberally too.  For the constructor case, you can always accept `NULL` pointers and instead throw at the point of use.
- You might consider using a `typedef` for your shared pointer type. One style that is sometimes used is follows:

  `typedef std::weak_ptr<Parent>    Parent_P;`

  `typedef std::shared_ptr<Parent>  Parent_WkP;`

  `typedef std::weak_ptr<Child>     Child_P;`

  `typedef std::shared_ptr<Child>   Child_WkP;`
- It's also useful to know that in header files you can forward declare `shared_ptr<Type>` without having seen a full declaration for `Type`.  This can save a lot of header bloat

Comment: I don't see any `shared_ptr<Child>` in the example. But you're right; use `weak_ptr` for back-references.

Comment: @BenHymers Fair enough! ;)

Comment: Regarding your first point: When I let the user pass a reference to a node then the user doesn't know that I use `shared_ptr` internally. I just tried it out and this resulted in a double-free error because first the node is destructed when it leaves scope and then later it is destructed again when the `shared_ptr` is destructed (Which results in a crash). So the user has to create a new node with `new` and must not `delete` it. But how shall the user know this? When the user is forced to pass a `shared_ptr` then this can't happen that easily. At least in my opinion.

Comment: Yes. This is the danger of passing by reference - and the possibility that the caller created the object on the stack.  The case for taking a reference is probably strongest when you are certain the object exists and is retained somewhere - most likely because you've just called `.get()` on an existing `shared_ptr`. I'm not personally a advocate of this approach, but I am aware some people are. I'd rather take the fairly minimal hit of constructing a shared_ptr and know there's no under-retaining or over-releasing.

Comment: I suggest removing the point about taking a reference, then turning it into a shared_ptr internally. It seems very dangerous for an API to take control of an object's memory like that. I'd expect an API to either: 1. Keep the reference, giving the caller the responsibility to keep the object alive. 2. Make a copy of the object (obviously not always possible). Or 3. Request a shared or unique ptr (unique_ptr can be passed by moving), making it clear to the caller that the API wants to control when the object gets deleted.

Comment: can you explain why `Child_WkP` is the non-weak pointer? It looks at first sight as if `WkP` is supposed to be a naming convention to document that it is a weak pointer.

Comment: Disagree with the typedef, it just makes it harder to read IMHO.

Comment: Especially as typedef's are NOT really the way to go for C++11. Use alias instead.

Answer (score 1):

The way that you are using shared pointers is correct with 2 caveats.

1. That your tree of parents and childen must share the lifetime of the pointers with other objects. If your Parent child tree will be the sole users of the pointer, please use a `unique_ptr`. If another object controls the lifetime of the pointer are you only want to reference the pointer, you may be better off using a `weak_ptr` unless the lifetime is guaranteed to exceed your Parent Child tree the raw pointer may be suitable.. Please remember that with `shared_ptr` you can get circular reference so it is not a silver bullet.
2. As for how to control NULL pointers: well this all comes down to the contract implicit in your API. If the user is not allowed to supply a null pointer, you just need to document this fact. The best way to do this is to include an `assert` that the pointer is not null. This will crash your application in debug mode (if the pointer is null) but will not incur a runtime penalty on your release binary. If however a null pointer is is an allowed input for some reason, then you need to provide correct error handling in the case of a null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Children do not own their parents. Rather, it's the other way around. If children need to be able to get their parents, then use a non-owning pointer or reference. Use shared (or better, unique if you can) pointer for parent to child.

Comment: In the real code it's a two-way connection. Parent contains a list of children. A child has a back-reference to its parent. I only showed the parent-reference in the example because that is much simpler than all the vector stuff needed for the children.